# How can i do something like 'expand all' link?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Is it possible to have all blocks opened on twitter bootstrap collapse plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the collapse plugin you may want to just use some jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .heading').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/auNu8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can just use the "in" class to do that...

`<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse **in**">`